# How do I get my logitech mouse to stop double clicking?

Tags: mouse, logitech-mouse

A week or 2 ago, my logitech darkfield mouse started double clicking things when I tried to single click them.  It also doesn't work when I try to click and drag anything.  Basically, the left mouse button randomly registers that it's been released when it hasn't.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Change the batteries.

Answer (score 3):

I had a Logitech mouse with this exact problem a few years ago and it turned out to be as simple as a worn-out left mouse button.

My answer: buy a new mouse.

Comment: yes it is likley that the switching mechanism is going closed then open again , based on the statement that holding it down (drag) it is not closed (switched). Depending on the operating system, the user could test "L mouse down" "L mouse up" functions as observed by the system and software. All keys and mouse click things are 2 steps, both the up and the down are sent via the software. There are 3rd party utilities that would show the state it was in, and help diagnose the problem.